# cohesion- ellipsis

Tags: lexical-relations, ellipsis, literacy

I'm currently analysing some of my old literacy work from primary school (5/6 years old), focussing on cohesion. When looking at ellipsis I find that I cannot place a category on what kind (if at all) of ellipsis this sentence includes;

"when they (the cars) see you they stop and you can go"

I believe "you can go refers" to 'you can cross the road'- is this an example of ellipsis?

Comment: Not really. _Stop_ and _go_, in the context of children crossing the street, is pretty straightforward. _Go_ does not mean 'cross the street' in general; only in this context, so there's no reason to think that something has been left out. Remember, if you claim ellipsis has occurred, you have to specify what was deleted.

Comment: Yep. No ellipsis there. (Could you give us the preceding sentences just in case?)